# Filter data based on from and until dates filter in node mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collection in MongoDB database that has some data and would like to filter and find data based on from and until dates.

Sample data

```
{
  "_id": "64958e4cd25792d403c05e83",
  "dealId": "4981506000014538111",
  "note": "short description 1123",
  "dateTime": "09/24/2022 12:22 AM",
  "nextId": null,
  "__v": 0
},
{
  "_id":"64958e4cd25792d403c05e86",
  "dealId": "4981506000014538111",
  "note": "big description",
  "dateTime": "06/23/2023 05:51 PM",
  "nextId": null
  "__v": 0
}
```

I used the following command to fetch data including from and until dates but it did not give me any results. Both startTime and endTime are in EST format. Not sure what am I missing. Please guide

```
const query = {
    $and: [
        { 
            dealId: dealId 
        },
        { 
            nextId: null 
        }
    ]
}; 
if (from && until) {
    query.$and.push({
        dateTime: {
            $gte: "06/23/2023",
            $lte: "09/24/2022"
        }
    })
}
const notes = await NotesModel.find(query);
```

Comment: The string `"AB"` is not less than or equal.to the string `"A"`. Similarly, the string `"09/24/2022 12:22 AM"` is not less than or equal to the string `"09/24/2022"`. It would be beneficial to store the information as dates rather than as strings precisely because of problems like this. You can probably adjust your query to get the desired document back now, but consider converting the data so that you don't have to jump through hoops to query it in the future

Comment: You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects

Comment: I agree with your answer. thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, you cannot compare date values when stored as string in local format. MongoDB does not support 12-hour times natively, I suggest to use a 3rd party Date library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/) and convert the strings to proper `Date` values. Here an example using `Luxon`:

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
db.NotesModel.find({ dateTime: { $type: "string" } }).toArray().forEach( doc => {
   let ts = DateTime.fromFormat(doc.dateTime, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a").toJSDate();
   db.NotesModel.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { dateTime: ts } })
})
```

Depending on the data size, this update may take some time.

Note, `DateTime` is parsed at [current time zone](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/zones), you may have to set the applicable time zone explicitly.

Then you can run your queries:

```
db.NotesModel.find({
   dateTime: {
      $gte: ISODate("2023-06-23"),
      $lte: ISODate("2022-09-24")
   }
})
```

However, this particular query will never return anything, because a date cannot be later than 2023-06-23 and earlier than 2022-09-24.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use dates with string. If you want to query on last week :

```
const currentDate= new Date()

from = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),
    currentDate.getMonth(),
    currentDate.getDate() + (7 - currentDate.getDay())

if (from && until) {
    query.$and.push({
        dateTime: {
            $gte: from,
            $lte: currentDate
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I agree with the spirit of this answer, namely that it's how such a query should normally be constructed. But I don't think it addresses the scenario and actual question that was raised